# Google scripts unhideRows not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script for Google Sheets I am working on.  I realize there are better ways to do what I am attempting (cough html/database cough), but I am required to make this spreadsheet work.

In short, I am trying to hide and unhide rows dynamically.  There does not appear to be a way to get filters to update without redoing them, so I am attempting to use hideRows to hide them and unhideRows to reveal them as needed.
The hideRows command works below.  The unhideRows command does not.  At this time, they are literally this close together in the code.  Originally, I was hiding on one sheet and unhiding on another, but set up like this to troubleshoot.  There is no filtering on this sheet (because it didn't work, I turned it off).  I tried setting the value in unhideRows directly to the value tested instead of a variable.
The row in question hides, but does not unhide.
I tried unhiding a different row just in case google was fumbling with hide this, unhide it back to back.  I am not getting unhide to work.

```
{  //thisRow = the row number of a range, in this case 2 if output to screen

    pImages.hideRows(thisRow);
    pImages.unhideRows(thisRow);
}
```

Comment: MrHoudini over on google forums pointed out the command showRows () adds the functionality I was expecting from unhideRows().

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer is not to unhideRows() which is the one the documents alluded to, but showRows () which does make more sense in everyday language.  Thanks again to Mr.Houdini on the Google forums.